# Updating the firebase database, getting an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, updates

This is my update method that should update the database:

```
function liked(useruid, likedUseruid){
      var postData = {
          useruid: 'Rich',
          likedUseruid: 'Hannah'
      };
      var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;
      var updates = {};
      updates['/users/' + useruid + '/' + 'liked/'] = postData;
      return firebase.database().ref().update(likedUseruid);
    }

    function disliked(){
      var people_unliked = [];
      people_unliked.push(useruid)
    }
```

I have hardcoded some values now for ease.

Below is my firebase structure. so why is the update failing with the error:

> Uncaught Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains an invalid key ([object MouseEvent]) in path /users/[object MouseEvent]/liked.

[image]

Comment: Can you paste your code that calls the `liked` function?

Comment: `document.getElementById('like').onclick = liked` @MathewBerg

Comment: How does it get the useruid and likedUseruid then?